# LicenseService.cs not found

Tags: imageresizer

I have a purchased license to use ImageResizer.Sqlreader, I have it working on one section of my site already, and now I'm trying to get it working on a separate section of our site. On my AddImage page (on localhost), the debugger is barfing on a line of code that says:

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, ms, resizeCropSettings)
```

It throws me to an error that says `"Source Not Found"` and `"LicenseService.cs not found"`. `"You need to find LicenseService.cs to view the source for the current call stack frame."`

I have the same ImageResizer NuGet packages installed in this project as I do in my already working project:

- ImageResizer v4.0.5
- ImageResizer.WebConfig v4.0.5
- ImageResizer.Storage v4.0.5
- ImageResizer.Sqlreader v4.0.5

[Gist of diagnostics page](https://gist.github.com/amywitty/dcc16c7c8be60475de720f9ab114ebb2)

#### Usage context

```
Dim resizeCropSettings As New ResizeSettings("maxwidth=1600&maxheight=1600&format=jpg&autorotate=true")

Using ms As New MemoryStream()
   ' Resize the image
   ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, ms, resizeCropSettings) ' *** Fails to step through here
    bytData = ms.ToArray()
End Using
```

Can you please advise? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did any other portion of the stack trace appear? Or does this only happen when you step into that line of code with the debugger? [You can grab LicenseService.cs](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/develop/Plugins/LicenseVerifier/LicenseService.cs) from github if you want to manually inform the debugger where to find it, but it might be easier just to skip that frame if possible.

Comment: No stack trace appeared. If I continued stepping through the debugger (or just hit Continue), the page would pretty much finish looking exactly like it started. No file uploaded, no redirect upon success. I never receive any error message, it just doesn't work.

Comment: There are no known scenarios where ImageResizer will fail silently. Could you share more of the surrounding code?

Comment: [AddImage.aspx](https://gist.github.com/amywitty/5777a871289d96e06f224fa3b840da98) [AddImage.aspx.vb](https://gist.github.com/amywitty/abe5b440f107dc376ca4890d155e81cc)

Comment: Thanks! I took the liberty of adding surrounding lines to your question. I would set a breakpoint on `End Using` and inspect the size/contents of bytData to see if it is empty or if it has data.

Comment: Setting the breakpoint there allowed me to continue troubleshooting, and I found the error in my other code to save the image to the db. The ImageResizer part was doing its thing properly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ImageResizer code in this question was working properly. The problem was due to an error in my code to save the Image item to the database (type mismatch). Setting the breakpoint as Nathanael suggested allowed me to debug past the "LicenseService.cs not found" error.